# Name of the View or iOS Component used in the gif?

Tags: ios, view, uicomponents

This is the way i need to create (gif).

[image: This is the way i need to create (gif)]

The Above gif shows a view which pops up from bottom while clicking on the moto g3 button overlaying the parent view with some gestures to control it.

I would like to know the name of this view if available in the iOS components or any specific ways to create it.

Comment: A modal view, with custom transition / animations.

Comment: @TomaszNazarenko Thanks for your response. Could you suggest any solutions to achieve this behaviour.